# Docker Desktop keeps removing all containers when let running for a period of time

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, docker-desktop, ubuntu-22.04

I am running Docker Desktop 4.17.0 on Ubuntu Desktop 22.04. I have four Docker Compose files with a total of 16 containers that operate the core functions of my machine. It seems that everything is operating perfectly until a certain point when I will notice that none of my services are available. Upon checking Docker Desktop, I see that the container section is entirely empty (It's giving me the guide on running a sample container).

Attempting to restart Docker Desktop using the toolbar icon locks it in the "Docker Desktop stopping mode..." mode until I kill all processes named Docker from the System Monitor. Reopening Docker Desktop after this loads up all of my containers as before, working perfectly. This continually loops 2-3 times a day.

I have tried entirely uninstalling Docker Desktop and Docker Engine to no avail. I'm unsure what's going on here. I've put a portion of the log from `/.docker/desktop/log/host` [here.](https://pastebin.com/8ce8VLMM)

Let me know what I'm missing!

Comment: I am having the EXACT same issue. Running v4.17 as well and Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.2 LTS. Mine does not happen this frequently, however. Maybe every day or two. My guess is something with 4.17 because it did not do this before I upgraded to 4.17. If you ever solve it - please post the solution! https://github.com/docker/desktop-linux/issues/131